# Understanding Non Blocking IO example

Tags: javascript, node.js

While reading node.js tutorial, I came across [this page](https://www.codeschool.com/blog/2014/10/30/understanding-node-js/) where they have explained the scenario using "Restaurant service" as an example.

In **Blocking IO** they have a code:

```
// requesting drinks for table 1 and waiting...
var drinksForTable1 = requestDrinksBlocking(['Coke', 'Tea', 'Water']);
// once drinks are ready, then server takes order back to table.
serveOrder(drinksForTable1);
// once order is delivered, server moves on to another table.
```

In **Non-blocking IO**, they have changed it to:

```
// requesting drinks for table 1 and moving on...
requestDrinksNonBlocking(['Coke', 'Tea', 'Water'], function(drinks){
  return serveOrder(drinks);
});
```

1. From what I understood, the second code will also take the same time to  execute and then move to next line of code. How to differentiate ?
2. Also, how to write 'function requestDrinksNonBlocking()' which can process array `['Coke', 'Tea', 'Water']` and then execute `serveOrder` using anonymous function.

Please help me understand the scenario.

Answer (score 1):

In the first example the `requestDrinksNonBlocking` execute and you use the output to call `serveOrder`

In the second example the `requestDrinksNonBlocking` takes a callback (`serveOrder`) which it will call when the request is done

Example of `requestDrinksNonBlocking` implementation

```
requestDrinksNonBlocking=function(drinks,callback){
    //Handle request from the array {drinks}
    callback(drinks);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> From what I understood, the second code will also take the same time to execute and then move to next line of code. How to differentiate ?

How much time this code will take in isolation is not what is important. In the second case something else can happen before the function passed as a callback is called so for example other requests can be handled instead of waiting.

> Also, how to write 'function requestDrinksNonBlocking()' which can process array ['Coke', 'Tea', 'Water'] and then execute serveOrder using anonymous function.

There are infinitely many answers to the question on how to write a function without telling what it should do exactly.